# Turn off Heroku Postgres database

Tags: heroku, heroku-postgres

How can I turn off Postgres database addon on a Heroku app? I have looked in various questions on SO and also visited Heroku documentation but was unable to find any help related to this.

Comment: What do you mean by "turn off"? Destroy it completely?

Comment: By turning offi  i mean to take it offline, without destroying data

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What are you trying to accomplish by doing this?

Comment: @Chris i can understand what you are saying,  But to explain further  what i wanted is, Some days ago we faced DDos attack on postgres That we are using which is provided by Heroku so I wanted to ask any way of turning/taking it offline for the time being, I tried putting it in maintenance mode but it was not of much help.

Answer (score 0):

You can reset the database, destroy the database or remove the addon on heroku, but then you lose all your data. Unless you made a backup.